# recyclerview is crashing when data is added from IntentService

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am getting the following error when I try to add new data to recyclerview from intentservice when the following line is called from addMsg function from the intentservice.How can I resolve it?

```
 new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getBaseContext()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Error:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
       at com.example.chat$SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.<init>(chat.java:471)
       at com.example.chat$8.run(chat.java:639)
```

Full code:

```
     public class CheeseListFragment extends Activity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.chat);


            setupRecyclerView(rv);

        }

        private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                    getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, 30)));
        }

        private List<String> getRandomSublist(String[] array, int amount) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(amount);
            Random random = new Random();
            while (list.size() < amount) {
                list.add(array[random.nextInt(array.length)]);
            }
            return list;
        }

        public static class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter
                extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

            private final TypedValue mTypedValue = new TypedValue();
            private int mBackground;
            private List<String> mValues;

            public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                public String mBoundString;

                public final View mView;
                public final ImageView mImageView;
                public final TextView mTextView;

                public ViewHolder(View view) {
                    super(view);
                    mView = view;
                    mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                    mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                }

                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    return super.toString() + " '" + mTextView.getText();
                }
            }

            public String getValueAt(int position) {
                return mValues.get(position);
            }

            public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
                context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, mTypedValue, true);
                mBackground = mTypedValue.resourceId;
                mValues = items;
            }

            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                view.setBackgroundResource(mBackground);
                return new ViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                holder.mBoundString = mValues.get(position);
                holder.mTextView.setText(mValues.get(position));

                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Context context = v.getContext();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheeseDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(CheeseDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME, holder.mBoundString);

                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                Glide.with(holder.mImageView.getContext())
                        .load(Cheeses.getRandomCheeseDrawable())
                        .fitCenter()
                        .into(holder.mImageView);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mValues.size();
            }
        }

 public void addMsg(String  msg_text){

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                mValues.add(chatmodel);

                new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getBaseContext()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(chat.getContext()));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getBaseContext()));
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mValues.add.size() - 1);



            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: where is your crash logs ?

Comment: You should not create a new `Adapter` everytime you get new data. Create one initially, make declare the object in your class and call `notifiDataSetChanged()` on it.

Comment: @Amy How can I make it work in this context ?

Comment: Above `onCreate`: `private SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;`, before `setAdapter`: `mAdapter = new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),
                    getRandomSublist(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings, 30));`, then `recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter)`, when you update data call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Also declare your `RecyclerView` above `onCreate` and set the `LayoutManager` once. (In `setupRecyclerView()`)

Comment: @Amy I tried : 
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and it crashes with an error: on a null object reference

Comment: I am trying to update from intentservice

Comment: Then `mAdapter` is apparently `null` when you call it. You are missing some basic experience in `Android`. If your `IntentService` is not in `CheeseListFragment.class`, you need to call a public method from `CheeseListFragment.class`, which will then update your interface with `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you have the issue with context.

```
 new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(getBaseContext()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Adapter use context to get LayoutInflater and inflate Views so you need to pass Activity context.

So create adapter inside Activity onCreate passing the Activity as context and on receive message just pass new data to the old adapter (don't create the new one)